# Why is Internet Explorer treating a file as a web page?

Tags: internet-explorer

I am trying to [download a Photoshop shape file](http://designmoo.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/cloud_shapes_designmoo_viaandrea.csh) (.csh), and instead of downloading it, IE treats it as a webpage and shows a series of symbols.

When I try to save it, I am told to either save as an html file or txt file. If I save as txt file and change the extension, Photoshop says it is invalid, since IE saves the text source, not the actual file.

I ended up having to use a download program to download it. Why is IE treating it as a webpage, and is there a way to fix the problem? Firefox shows the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the server's giving it the wrong Content-Type header. m4573r's answer might serve as a workaround; I'd also report it as a server issue to whoever runs designmoo.com.

Comment: After downloading and trying this in chrome, it seems to indeed be a server issue, and I have contacted the owners of the website.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

1. Click on the link
2. Choose **Save as...**
3. Choose **Text file** in **Save as type:**
4. Choose **Unicode** in **Encoding:**
5. Click save
6. Change the extension of the newly saved file.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the link

[image: right click menu]

Select **Save Target As...**

In the save box that appears
[image: Save file dialog]
change **save as type:** to *All Files*

Comment: Clear workaround.